# I get an error when I use the command Announce

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I was testing my command I got an error, that I have tried fixing many times, but I still can't get it to work.
Here is the announce code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
    if(!msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.reply('You can\'t use that!');
    const channel = msg.mentions.channels.first() || msg.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === args[0])
    if(!channel) return msg.reply("channel not found!")
    const announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    if(!announcement) return msg.reply("Please give an announcement")
    var embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("BLUE")
    .setTitle("Announcement!")
    .setDescription(`**${announcement}**`)
    .setFooter(msg.auther.displayAvaterURL, msg.auther.tag({ dynamic: true}))
    channel.send(embed)
}
```

Everything works without the footer, but I would like to have it in.
Here is the error I get:

```
(node:8976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined
    at Object.exports.run (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\commands\announce.js:12:27)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\index.js:28:14)
    at Client.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\spil\Firlingdon & xEpic_Wolf Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:375:28)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8976) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And when I switch around displayAvaterURL,
It just replaces with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayAvaterURL'
```

Comment: You misspelled `auther`- it's `author`. Furthermore, `displayAvatarURL()` is a function and `tag` is a property, so switch around the code accordingly.

Comment: Please give me an example.

Comment: @Emiluvik Here you can find examples: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
    if (!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return msg.reply("You can't use that!")
    const channel =
        msg.mentions.channels.first() || msg.guild.channels.cache.find((c) => c.id === args[0])
    if (!channel) return msg.reply("channel not found!")
    const announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    if (!announcement) return msg.reply("Please give an announcement")
    var embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("BLUE")
        .setTitle("Announcement!")
        .setDescription(`**${announcement}**`)
        .setFooter(message.author.tag,message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))

    channel.send(embed)
}
```

Comment: @Emiluvik i made some changes, try again now

Comment: TypeError: msg.author.displayAvaterURL is not a function
Does That code work for you?

Comment: It is hard to debug somone elses command, since I only have that part of the code. but I made some changes again, and the footer works for me now

Comment: Could you please click the check mark aswell? So other users know, that this question has been answered and resolved